# He will/must/might/could be at home till now

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, grammaticality, modal-verbs

"He will/must/might/could be at home till now".

"Shop will/must/might/could be open till now"an I Could I use "model verb" with "till now"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Till now* is not very common in English, and usually only used when something that has always been the case has changed: something has just stopped happening, or started happening.

> This has never happened till now. (implies that it has now happened)

> Somebody has always been there till now (implies that now, somebody is not there).

These have a sense of "always until now", which doesn't work with the modals you are talking about.

But if you substitute *by now* (= now or before now), they work:

(Approximate equivalents after "="):

> He will be home by now = I expect/deduce that he is home by now.

> He must be home by now = I conclude/strongly expect that he is home by now.

> He could be home by now = I think it is possible that he is home by now.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Till" requires a duration. It is not an instant in time.

You could say, "He might be home now." But it doesn't make sense to say, "He might be home till now." There's no time span there. You could say, "He might have been at home till now" or "He might have been home from 8 am until now."

Comment: thanks but does it make sense if context is " he was at home and now he is free to leave"?

Comment: @BilalZafar: the most idiomatic way of saying that is _so far_: "He is at home so far" - implies that I don't know whether he will stay. You could also say _at the moment_, but that also doesn't say whether he has been home for a while, or has only just got home. _Up to now_ is also possible, though it feels less natural to me. See my answer for what _till now_ usually means.

Comment: @Colin Fine.cheers.With due respect, Do you not think istead of saying "He is at home so far" we must say "He has been at home so far" because grammatically "present perfect should be used with "so far"

Comment: @BilalZafar: both are possible. _has been_ is probably more common, but we can say _He is at home so far_ if we are focussing on the future from now rather than the time up to now.

Comment: @BilalZafar I would say, "He has been at home all day [or whatever period of time] but now he is leaving." Or some variation of that depending on exactly what you're trying to say.